# Difficulty finding minimal polynomial...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

I would like to find the minimal polynomial of the following matrix.

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
1& 2& 0& 0 \\ 
2& 1& 1& 1 \\
0& 0& 1& 2 \\
0& 0& 0& 1
\end{pmatrix}. $$

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is
$$ c_A(x) = x^4 - 4x^3 + 2x^2 + 4x - 3 = (x-3)(x-1)^2(x+1). $$
Thus, the minimal polynomial must be either $c_A(x)$ or $(x-3)(x-1)(x+1)$.

Yet, neither $(A - 3I)(A-I)(A+I)$ nor $(A - 3I)(A-I)^2(A+I)$ yields the zero matrix (I double checked this in Mathematica).

I can't figure out what I've done wrong here...

EDIT:

Indeed, I simply made a computational error (though I can't quite figure out exactly where...)

Comment: it works fine. I think you had better type in what you think $A-3I,$ $(A-I)^2,$ and $A + I$ are. Then $(A-3I)(A-I)^2$

Comment: But the characteristic polynomial *must* give the zero matrix, so there must be some mistake either in getting $c_A(x)$ or in evaluating $c_A(A)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your computation of matrix product, it works for me.

```
octave:1> A = [ 1, 2, 0 , 0; 2, 1, 1, 1; 0, 0, 1, 2; 0, 0, 0, 1]
A =

   1   2   0   0
   2   1   1   1
   0   0   1   2
   0   0   0   1
octave:2> (A - 3* eye(4)) * (A -eye(4))*(A+eye(4))
ans =

   0   0   0   4
   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0  -8
   0   0   0   0

octave:3> (A - 3* eye(4)) * (A -eye(4))*(A-eye(4))*(A+eye(4))
ans =

   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0
```

The minimal polynomial is the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: One way to see this "by inspection" is to note the block triangular structure of $A$.